# Why can't I return a value from a void function in Java?

Tags: java

Correct the following erroneous definition of method getAge()

```
public void getAge() 
{
   return age;
}
```

Paste your answer in here:

```
public int getAge(int age) 
{ 
return age; 
}
```

Mark: 0 out of 1

Comments:

```
* Test 1 (0.0 out of 1)

      Person.java:15: getAge(int) in Person cannot be applied to ()
              String s = (p.getAge() == 16 ? "getAge() Correct" : "getAge() not Correct");
                           ^
      1 error
      The output should have been:
          getAge() Correct

      This is what was actually produced:
          Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Person
```

instead of (int age) does it want me to replace it with a String?

Comment: Just remove the parameter and pick `this.age`.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the correct code you're looking for is:

```
public int getAge() 
{ 
  return age; 
}
```

basically saying that getAge() requires no parameters (where your mistake was, you had one integer parameter being passed in) and it will return a value of type int.

Answer (score 2):

No it wants you to give it the correct return type!

```
public int getAge() 
{
   return age;
}
```

Comment: what arguments?  There's no arguments in this accessor!  It's the wrong return type (void) that was specified!!

Comment: He got the answer half right.  He corrected the return type from void to int, but neglected to remove the "int age" argument to the accessor method.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the [java compiler](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/javac.html) in command line (or a decent IDE) to understand what is going on.  (You seem to be just pasting code in your school's homework test harness and getting cryptic errors.)

What does this mean?

```
  This is what was actually produced:
      Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Person
```

It means that the homework test harness tried compiling your `Person` class and it couldn't (see below) and then the test harness ran and couldn't find a Person class (because it didn't compile).

Here is the problem:

```
public void getAge() 
{
   return age;
}
```

A method returning `void` can't return a value.  (If you had used [javac](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/javac.html), the compiler would have told you that.)

So age is an int and you need to return it:

```
public int getAge() 
{
   return age;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesnt want the parameter. You return a value of a property of the object (p in this case).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that it's trying to apply your `getAge(int)` function to a call to `getAge()`. Go back and think again about what `getAge` is trying to do, and what information (arguments) it should need to do it. Then rewrite your function definition.